# Duplicate Http requests using service Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, post, duplicates, httprequest

I am trying to remove an object from my database in an .Net Core 2.1 + Angular Application. Every time I make my call however two records are created.

While debugging it appears that the call is made and happens twice. The network tab of the console show two duplicate calls and when listening on the server each breakpoint is iterated through twice. These calls happen in unison, not sequentially, as I have to click through each breakpoint twice before proceeding to the next.

I have looked into using the share operator, but either its not helping or i'm not implementing it right?

Any help appreciated,

**Module.ts**

```
import { BusinessUnitService } from './../../services/business- 
unit.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Component({
selector: 'app-businessunit-create',
templateUrl: './businessunit-create.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./businessunit-create.component.css']
})

export class BusinessunitCreateComponent implements OnInit {

companies = [];
businessUnit: any = {};

constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BusinessunitCreateComponent>,
private businessUnitService: BusinessUnitService,
private toastr: ToastrService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.businessUnitService.getCompanies().subscribe(res => {
  this.companies = res;
  console.log(res);
});
}

createBusinessUnit() {
console.log(this.businessUnit);
this.businessUnitService.addBusinessUnit(this.businessUnit).share().subscribe(res => {
  this.toastr.success('New Line of Business added successfully');
  this.dialogRef.close('ok');
},
  err => {
        this.toastr.error('Line of Business could not be added: ' + err);
});
}
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BusinessUnitService {

addBusinessUnit(bu) {
   return this.http.post('/BusinessUnit/NewBusinessUnit', bu).pipe(share());
}
```

**HTML Where called**

```
 <mat-dialog-actions>
<button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button>
<button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="createBusinessUnit()" 
    [disabled]="!f.valid">Save Line of Business</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

*Edited for clarity

Comment: "While debugging it appears that the call is made and happens" - Do you see one HTTP call being made, or two?

Comment: When debugging, the HTTP call is made twice. The function on the controller side is called twice and the network tab of the console shows two calls.

Comment: To troubleshoot, you might want to put a `debugger` statement in the method that is called twice. The browser dev tools will stop at that point, and you can inspect the stack trace to see where the calls are coming from.

Comment: Please post your code of piping method 'share()'. I suspect the problem is from there.

Comment: I see that you have `import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';` (rxjs5) and `import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';` (rxjs6+). I assume you are using rxjs-compat to be able to use both, but I don't know if that can cause some kind of conflict. If you remove `.share()` in your component the result changes somehow? Also, just to make sure, your method `createBusinessUnit()` is called only once?

Comment: I used 'import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';' first and then the rxjs5 version after. I have implemented both independently and neither have resolved my issue. 'CreateBusinessUnit()' is definitely only called a single time.

Comment: If your server is in a different origin, it will send 2 requests, 1 `HTTP OPTIONS` and another with `POST` (due to `CORS`). You should process only the `POST` in your server (or the 2 processes you see are `POST`?).

Comment: I believe both processes I see are Posts. On the server side my function has the [HttpPost] before the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, even though my component.ts only called the function twice, it turns out I had put the function name in my  header. Since I did

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createBusinessUnit()" #f="ngForm">
```

this function was called when I hit the "submit" button of my form which called the function again. The result was that the Angular function that called my http service was called twice when i hit the button on the bottom of the screen.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="buName">Name: </label>
    <input id="buName" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="businessUnit.Name" name="buName" required #buName="ngModel">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="(buName.touched || buName.dirty) && !buName.valid">
      Please provide a Name for Line of Business.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="buNameKey">Name Key:</label> <br/>
  <small> *Warning: NameKey must be unique among Lines of Business</small>
  <input id="buNameKey" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="businessUnit.NameKey" name="buNameKey"
  #buNameKey="ngModel" required minlength="3" maxlength="3">
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="(buNameKey.touched) && !buNameKey.valid">
  <div *ngIf="buNameKey.errors.required">
    Please provide a 3 character Name Key.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="buNameKey.errors.minlength">
    Name Key must be at least 3 characters long.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="buDesc"> Description: </label>
 <input id="buDesc" name="buDesc" type="text" class="form-control" 
[(ngModel)]="businessUnit.Description">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="company">Company</label>
<select id="company" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="businessUnit.CompanyID" 
name="company" required #company="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let company of companies" value="{{company.item1}}"> 
  {{company.item2}}</option>
</select>
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="company.touched && !company.valid">
   Please select a Company.
</div>
</div>
<mat-dialog-actions>
<button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button>
<button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="createBusinessUnit()" 
[disabled]="!f.valid">Save Line of Business</button>
 </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: You could also add a type of `submit` to the `<button>`, remove the `(click)`, and keep the `(ngSubmit)="createBusinessUnit()"` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Came across duplicate requests and found out there were duplicate function calls each in form tag and button event. Removed the (click) event and replaced it with Type="submit"

**ERROR**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="verifyLogin()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <button (click)="verifyLogin()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
```

**FIX**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="verifyLogin()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
```